# facing issues regarding creation of mysql events

Tags: mysql, events, scheduler

Hi I am facing issues regarding adding mysql events in mysql

even switched on event scheduler status

it shows event created but nothing is been added

i am using mysql phpmyadmin

Comment: There isn't enough here to provide and answer - please add your event code and an explanation of what it is meant to do.

Comment: SET GLOBAL event_scheduler="ON" ,

CREATE EVENT pages_insert ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND DO insert into active_pages(name) values('vivek')

Comment: Other than the missing ; after SET GLOBAL event_scheduler="ON"  the event code works as expected. I suggest you try this on sqlfiddle or dbfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Events are run by the scheduler, it's not started by default. Using SHOW PROCESSLIST command it is possible to check whether it started or not. if its not started then run the command before your query in phpmyadmin.

```
 SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

or you can check mysql.cnf file set event_schedler = ON for permanent solution

```
[mysqld]
event_scheduler = ON
```

Comment: Thanx for replying. But I have executed that command.Even the event was created But not shown I have tried about 20 times.